# Can I query Graph API for suggested bid in Ads API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to query Facebook Ads API for suggested bid for ABSOLUTE_OCPM. Facebook interface provides default absolute OCPM bid, but I can't find it anywhere in Facebook documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Info can be found here: [Facebook Ads API docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/reachestimate)